# Multi-master AXI interface connections

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, test-bench, amba

Do we need to have three instantiations of AXI master interface in top file if we have 3 AXI masters and then send these three interfaces to 3 AXI agent instantiations using the config_db?  Or, how does it work in case of a multi-master scenario to make connections of interface with the DUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to fully verify your DUT, you need one `interface` in your testbench for each DUT interface.  Since your DUT has 3 AXI interfaces, you need 3 AXI `interface` instances in the testbench, and you add all 3 of them to the `uvm_config_db` to be passed to each AXI agent.